# I cannot retrieve & display images from MYsql to table column

Tags: php, mysql, image

My table and code I am giving below

```
Table_gnews |
+-------------------+
| gnewsid=>int      |                
| gnewsh=>varchar   | 
| gnewsd=>varchar   | 
| gnewsimg=>longblob|

<table id="exampleN" class="display table table-striped table-bordered nowrap dt-responsive" style="font-size: smaller;">
 <thead>
   <tr>                         
     <th style="background-color:lightcoral;">Image</th>
     <th style="background-color:lightgray;">Date</th>
     <th style="background-color:lightgray;">News HeadLines</th>
     <th style="background-color:lightgray;">News Details</th>  
   </tr>
   </thead>                 
   <tbody>
    <?php if (count($data5)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($data5 as $key => $row4): ?> 
   <tr>
    <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode"><?php echo   $row4['gnewsimg']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row4['gnewsdate']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row4['gnewsh']; ?></td>
  </tr>                     
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Now I insert image one by one, but it is very time-consuming.

What is my planning is: I store all the images in my website server not in MySQL database because I don't want to unnecessary DB size increase and keep in the database reference to that file.**
**Example:
My images are in the server like www/images/logo/ and there are images like l1.jpg,l2.jpg etc.

And I want to create a varchar field in my SQL database and that field containing the only file name and display the images on my website.

How I will do it?

Comment: the image value is added outside the src attribute

Comment: can you please give more details

Comment: have you save the physical path of your image in DB or you have encode the image in base64 and then saved in DB?

Comment: can you please give more details? I save the image to desktop and upload in MySQL.What is the wrong with my code?

Comment: why u dont just store in folder ? if store in db , u need a very powerful server to process it , if u run in www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below for the image

```
echo ' <img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $row4['gnewsimg'] ).'"/>';
```

Comment: I have one question if you have no problem to answer.Question is: how I will upload bulk images to MYSQL database.I am doing one by one now